# Exporting Eclipse plugin not able to see project as plugin project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on Eclipse plugin. At the beginning exporting of it worked fine but I guess that after updating Eclipse it broke down. Eclipse started to mentioned that I have uninstalled some equinox packages. It took time till I understood that version of Eclipse made a problems and I reinstalled older version of Eclipse. Now I am again able to run sample environment with plugin but I still am not able to export plugin. In export form where I need to select deployable plugin and/or fragments I don't have listed anything. From what I found I understand that it might be problem with importing project in Eclipse as it might not remove information that project is external and thus not listing as project that could be exported. But I did not find any way to prove this case.

Is there anybody having any idea how to solve this kind of issue?

Comment: Sorry, but this is very hard to follow. Show us details of the project such as the MANIFEST.MF and the .project file.

Comment: Here is [MANIFEST.MF](https://github.com/Mafioziks/JEB__Extension/blob/update-and-fix/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) file and here is [.project](https://github.com/Mafioziks/JEB__Extension/blob/update-and-fix/.project) file. @greg-449

Comment: Your question tells the project is not shown as plugin project, your `.project` it's a non-Java plugin project and your `MANIFEST.MF` tells it's a Java plugin project. If the `MANIFEST.MF` is right, in `.project` the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder` builder and `org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature` nature is missing.

Comment: @howlger I tried to add both natures, refresh project and even restarted eclipse but it did not made any changes for me.

Comment: Add it as a builder and a nature: `<buildCommand><name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name><arguments/></buildCommand>` and `<nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for me why it not showing it in the export list is because I selected "**Binary projects**" in **Import As-Import Plug-ins and Fragments**.
I change it to "**Projects with source folders**". This can then be displayed in "Deployable plug-ins and fragments".

[image]
[image]